# Visiting Germany on Schengen visa while applying for a spousal visa

Tags: visas, germany, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas

I'm applying for a family reunification visa to join my wife in Germany. I am an Indian national resident in the UK. I will get to keep my passport since the processing time is over six weeks. I also have a valid Schengen visa.

Can I use the Schengen visa to visit her while my family reunification visa is being processed?

I don't see anything explicitly forbidding it but I believe other countries don't allow it. What is the case for Germany?

Comment: Where are *you* from? Visa rules depend on your nationality. Don't know if this specific one does, but for example, citizens of "Western" nations don't even need to apply in their home country, they can just come on their regular "free" 90 days and apply here in Germany. Whether that is a good idea considering the snail pace the German "Amts" work is another question though.

Comment: Also, what *is* your currently valid Visa? I have a hard time believing you would have to quit your job or stop studying in Germany, just because you applied for family reunification.

Comment: @nvoigt updated details. I am not in Germany and am applying for the spousal visa from the UK where I am resident.

Comment: It might be restricted to get *another, new* Visa in parallel to your application, but if you currently already *have* a valid Visa, I have not seen anything that would suggest that is invalidated by applying for family reunification. I cannot really prove a negative though...

Comment: @nvoigt, the new visa would be a national one, while the current one is a Schengen visa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the visa officer and found out that this is completely okay.